# (C++) My custom array cannot be initialized (compile error)

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, std

I created a custom array inheriting std::array.
But it cannot be initialized using the same statement for std::array.
Could anyone let me know why this does not work and help me out to correctly modify my code?

Here is the compile error messages :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:32:35: error: no matching function for call to 'my_array::my_array()'
     my_array<int, 2>   b { {1, 2} }; // compile error
                                   ^
main.cpp:13:8: note: candidate: my_array::my_array()
 struct my_array : std::array<T,N>
        ^
main.cpp:13:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
main.cpp:13:8: note: candidate: constexpr my_array::my_array(const my_array&)
main.cpp:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '' to 'const my_array&'
main.cpp:13:8: note: candidate: constexpr my_array::my_array(my_array&&)
main.cpp:13:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '' to 'my_array&&'
```

---

Below is the code for my implementation.
Thanks in advance.

---

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct my_array : std::array<T,N>
{
    T& operator[](std::size_t n)
    {
        if(!(n < N))
            std::cout << "out of range" << std::endl;
        return (*static_cast<std::array<T,N>*>(this))[n];
    }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t n) const
    {
        if(!(n < N))
            std::cout << "out of range" << std::endl;
        return (*static_cast<const std::array<T,N>*>(this))[n];
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 2> a { {1, 2} }; // no error
    my_array<int, 2>   b { {1, 2} }; // compile error
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `operator[]` functions are without bounds-checking for a reason. If you want bounds-checking use [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) instead.

Comment: if(n > N) it is out of bound looks like you are doing opposite.

Comment: Pretty sure you've run afoul of rules against using aggregate initialization with a base class in a pre-C++17 compiler. Trying to find the exact ruling. Haven't had much opportunity to use C++17.

Comment: Typically, if one asks about compilation errors, one must include them into the question (they, typically, state exactly what's wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I would say your custom class doesn't know about a constructor with parameter initializer_list so you have to implement this on your own.

A quick and dirty solution based on your code, but compiling and executing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct my_array : std::array<T,N>
{
  my_array(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    {
      int i=0;
      for(auto val = list.begin();val != list.end();val++) {
        std::array<T,N>::at(i++) = *val;
      }
    }


  T& operator[](std::size_t n)
    {
      if(n < N)
        std::cout << "out of range" << std::endl;
      return (*static_cast<std::array<T,N>*>(this))[n];
    }
  const T& operator[](std::size_t n) const
    {
      if(n < N)
        std::cout << "out of range" << std::endl;
      return (*static_cast<const std::array<T,N>*>(this))[n];
    }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::array<int, 2> a { {1, 2} }; // no error
  my_array<int, 2>   b { {1, 2} }; // compile error
  std::cout << b.at(0) << ", " << b.at(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` uses [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Unfortunately until C++17 a class with a base cannot be an aggregate, and that eliminates `my_array`.

From **[dcl.init.aggr]** in N3291 (earliest post C++11 standard draft I have available)

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

C++14 weakens these requirements a little (N4140)

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

The restrictions against base classes remains.

Current Standards revisions rewrite the relevant paragraph into

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 12) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors (15.1),
>
> (1.2) — no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 14),
>
> (1.3) — no virtual functions (13.3), and
>
> (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (13.1).

Which allows `public` base classes

AltruisticDelay's answer works around this limitation with a `std::Initializer_list`. If you are restricted in your choice of compilers or Standard support, this is probably the right answer for you.

If you can compile into C++17 or a more recent Standard, the code posted in the question will compile without modification.